# Meaning of "___ does not pretend to speak for everyone"

Tags: phrases, idioms

"The committee does not pretend to speak for every member of the association"

What are some of the meanings behind the sentence above? Is this sentence used to suggest that the committee works hard to represent the association, or is it to merely emphasize that the committee cannot *ever* represent the whole?

Comment: It means that the committee, a subset of the association, has issued a report of its findings but that it doesn't represent that report as having the support of the entire association.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It acknowledges that there will be members of the association who have a different opinion to that put forward by the committee. It could be focused on saying that the committee does not have the authority to make a statement on behalf of every member, and/or that members are free to express a different opinion if they wish.